# Can't remove border because of colspan in Chrome

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Consider following code

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

td.nb {
  border: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="nb" colspan="3">Foo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>World</td>
    <td class="nb">Bar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="nb" colspan="3">Foo</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want column "Bar" to have no border but for some reason in comes with borders (top+bottom)

**How can I remove  borders?**

[image]

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rwLQWG

Comment: i do not see any border... using FF. issue is on chrome though

Comment: @tech2017 so it's chrome thing...

Comment: Hmmm, if you change `border-collapse: collapse;` to `border-collapse: separate;` it goes away

Comment: @Peter yes, tried with IE and it is displayed correctly

Comment: @j08691 you are right but then borders are separate...

Comment: Yeah I was just noting that as odd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [known Chrome issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=356132), and quite an annoying one at that.

> April 1 2014
>
> It's a known (old) issue in our table code. Collapsing borders are determined based on adjacent cells and our code doesn't deal correctly with spanning cells (we only consider the cell adjoining the first row / column in a row / column span). On top of that, our border granularity is determined by the cell's span.
>
> To fix this bug, we would need to overhaul our collapsing border code, which is a big undertaking.

*(Credit to [Paolo Forgia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1685157/paolo-forgia)'s alternate [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44525122/2026606), which was the first to note the Chromium thread.)*

---

Separating the borders would be an option, but I know that I personally dislike working with separated cell-borders; You run into issues where every other cell has to have a border on only one side and it becomes quite the headache, not to mention the convolution of CSS markup.

A workaround that would enable you to keep your collapsable borders would be something like the one below. It creates a pseudo-element in the cell that covers the red borders with white ones.

```css
body {
    background: white;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid red;  
}
td.nb {
  border: 0 !important;
}

/* New class for cells affected by this issue */
td.nbtb {
  position: relative;
  border: 0 !important;
}

/* Pseudo-element to cover up the borders */
td.nbtb::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% + 1px);
  border: 1px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="nb" colspan="3">Foo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>World</td>
    <td class="nbtb">Bar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="nb" colspan="3">Foo</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks +1 I am sorry that  awarded another guy while your workaround will look better he was just faster. This is a browser bug, and I took that for answer.

Comment: @Peter Early bird gets the worm I suppose. Paolo did a nice job of finding the Chromium bug-report thread.

Comment: @Peter faster isn't always better. I'm very happy that you accepted mine, I'm also glad to have been helpful. However Santi's workaround looks better and after the last edit the answer looks more complete than mine in general. In any case I would for sure update mine to be more reliable

Comment: @PaoloForgia i changed the accepted answer. i am not using any of workarounds mentioned here, I broke the colspan into two pieces as I was fortunate enough to be able to do it in real code

Comment: I edited your answer a bit.  From what I saw here @ShammelLee workaround looks the most rational as I would rather force browser to work in HTML4+HTML5 quirk mode than edit table classes and use `white border+calc+td as block+pseudo classes+absolute&relative positioning` - it works buts it's a huge hack :)

Comment: I apologize but I'm going to have to refute your edit - `calc()` and pseudo-elements are *CSS properties*. They are completely unrelated to which version of HTML you're using.

Comment: `They are completely unrelated to which version of HTML you're using.` what about white border? an requirment to use 3 classes and requritment to add `nrb` class before no-border cell? i am grateful you try to help and I agree  we should kill previous decade browsers but your workaround is one hell of a hack. forget `cell` what I am saying this is NOT how you style tables and this is NOT how you should recommend future visitors to deal with the problem. While this MAY be workaround you should say it clearly - THIS IS NOT PERFECT THERE MAY BE OTHER PTIONS

Comment: Hey santi i am not hostile at all sorry if you think that way! I am really grateful for your help. Your workaround is a hack not something people should use as general solution - that's all I am saying. SO have huge impact in web and people will copy your css. And I think **absolutely positiong table cells is just so bad practice >it should be at least mentioned as "one of many workarounds"<** I just splitted the <td> in two, browser bug, the only sane choice I could do. Someone else reading this topic in future should see this is an option too.

Comment: You have to edit classes of two columns, change table cells to absolutely positioned `block` and you use pseudoelements to make cell border. It's css hack. I'll keep your answer accepted as "this is a chrome bug and there are workarounds" is an answer.

Comment: I am sorry of course you are right you only change table cell to relative, and you only add pseudoclass to table cell - there is no need to be hostile. **Still - this is hack, you normally don't add pseudoelements to table cells**. I didn't really wanted to say it but android kitkat have 20% market share I can't drop these users yet like IE6-7 users. I don't want discussion about it. Just please just drop the ego for one second - **your workaround is excellent** but there are other options and literally all I said is - it's worth to mention that there are other options.

Comment: Regarding other options - I used `<td colspan="x">X</td><td colspan="y" class="nb">Y</td>` in real life code, as text is short and aligned to left. Future visitors will find your answer. They should be aware they can do this and your answer is not ultimate. If you think adding pseudoclasses to table cells is good practice to work around browser bugs is OK I can't help you. That's literally all I am saying.

Answer (score 3):

It is a known (and old) [bug of Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=356132) that affect version 33.0.1750.154 or later.

As workaround you can use:

```
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 0;
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

td.nb {
  border: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="nb" colspan="3">Foo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>World</td>
    <td class="nb">Bar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="nb" colspan="3">Foo</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The workaround does not completely have the same result. The border between "Hello" and "World" is 2 pixels.

Comment: You're right, in fact I upvoted Santi's answer too. However I see my answer as a temporary workaround until Chrome fix the problem without having to make too many changes to the table's css.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `border-collapse` and add `cellspacing=0` and `cellpadding=0` to your table. Then change your CSS to the following…

```css
td {
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 0 1px 1px;  
}

td:nth-last-child(2) {
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}

td.nb {
  border: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
  <tr>
    <td class="nb" colspan="3">Foo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>World</td>
    <td class="nb">Bar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="nb" colspan="3">Foo</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```